# Utilizar outra caixa de pesquisa sem ser o padrão do DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatable

Olá, que saber se é possível eu utilizar uma caixa de pesquisa que eu faça na mão e acrescente da minha tabela que tem o DataTable sem afetar o plug-in. Por que um exemplo eu tava pensando fazer filtragem por um input de data. Agredeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema:
colocamos isso no style:

```
    <style>
    .dataTables_filter { 
        display: none; 
    }
</style>
```

Meu js

```
 $("#filter-input").keyup(function() {
     var pesquisar = $(this).val();
     tabela.search(pesquisar).draw();
     });
  });
```

E nas configurações do DataTable tem deixar:

```
"searching": true
```